# A scheduled task to a discord bot in python fails to do its job

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I am programming a discord bot in python. It needs to sweep the member list every 24hrs, check their roles and do some actions accordingly. I started to program this, but the scheduled task apparently doesn't have access to discord. I can't seem to get a member. When I do this in a command:

```
@bot.command(name='sweepercmd', help='')
async def sweepercmd(ctx):
    member = get(bot.get_all_members(), name="Waldstein")
    print(member)
```

It prints "Waldstein#4164" in the bash console as expected. However if I put the same code in a task like this:

```
@tasks.loop(hours=24.0)
async def sweeper():
    member = get(bot.get_all_members(), name="Waldstein")
    print(member)
```

It prints "None". Adding ctx like ...sweeper(ctx)... makes it hang.
How can I access discord within my task just like in the commands?
thanks in advance for the help,
Jo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for why your tasks are failing, I'm not entirely sure, but I'll look into it for you and edit my answer when I get some info on it. In the mean time, this should suffice:

You can use `loop.create_task()` as an alternative for this.

```py
async def sweep_task():
    while True:
        member = discord.utils.get(bot.get_all_members(), name="Waldstein")
        print(member)
        await asyncio.sleep(86400)

@bot.command()
async def sweep(ctx): # doesn't necessarily need to go into a command - you could put it into
                      # your on_ready event if you want to
    bot.loop.create_task(sweep_task())
```

---

**References:**

- [`Client.loop`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.loop)
- [`Client.get_all_members()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_all_members)
- [`utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)
- [`loop.create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task)
- [`asyncio.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep)

Comment: This is a valid work around. Thanks again Diggy. I'd like to buy you a coffee someday!